# Suppressing line specific XCode compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, compiler-warnings

Similar to [Ben Gottlieb's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622017/suppressing-deprecated-warnings-in-xcode), I have a handful of deprecated calls that are bugging me. Is there a way to suppress warnings by line? For instance:

```
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 } else {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; //causes deprecation warning
 }
```

All I care about is that line. I don't want to turn off *all* deprecation warnings. I would also rather not do something like [suppress specific warnings by file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764735/specific-compiler-flags-for-specific-files-in-xcode).

There have been a few other circumstances where I wanted to flag a specific line as okay even though the compiler generates a warning. I essentially want to let my team know that the problem has been handled and stop getting bugged about the same line over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vincent Gable](http://vgable.com/blog/2009/06/15/ignoring-just-one-deprecated-warning/) has posted an interesting solution.  In short:

```
@protocol UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
```

---

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide]; 
} else { 
    id<UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods> app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Cool. I guess that works for dodging the deprecation warnings. The more abstract question is still open, however. Is there a way to suppress a specific warning in XCode?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's mostly all or nothing.  Through the use of `#pragma GCC diagnostic ...` (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), you can disable a specific warning on a per-file basis in a more obvious way than the per-file build settings.  It does require GCC 4.2+, and must be placed at the very top of a translation unit.

Comment: @matt-b FYI, I think I found a better way to deal with the deprecation warnings. If I cast UIApplication to (id) the error goes away. Can you think of a reason this is improper?

Comment: @MrHen: Yes, that does sometimes work.  When you send `id` a selector, the compiler checks to ensure that at least _some_ class is able to respond to such a selector.  That may not always be the case with a deprecated selector.  If not, a no method found warning is raised.  Thus, adding a protocol is the more robust solution; it will always circumvent the warning.

Comment: This works for me, but I do have to make one change.  My code reads:
  id<UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods> app = (id)[UIApplication sharedApplication];

Otherwise that line gives me a warning.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I generally do it all in one line (`(id<UIApplicationDeprecatedMethods>)[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`), but I broke it into two for the post for readability.  Thanks for the note, @William.

Comment: @MattB.: "the compiler checks to ensure that at least some class is able to respond to such a selector." The compiler simply cares that it is declared *somewhere* in the current scope. It doesn't care where. Since you are getting a deprecated warning, it is declared somewhere as deprecated. So using `id` will always work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
  respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 } else {
  [(id)[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
 }
```