# Dealing with deprecated methods in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-warnings, deprecated

How do you deal with deprecated methods in iPhone that require you to use a newer method, not available in older versions?

Consider the case of `setStatusBarHidden:animated:`, which was deprecated in iOS 3.2. The documentation points you to use `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:`, which is only available in iOS 3.2 or later.

If I understand correctly, this means that to target all devices (iOS 3.0 or later), I have to ask first if `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` is available. If it is, use it. If not, use the deprecated method. But I would still get a warning of deprecation.

Is this correct (please say it isn't!)? If it is, is there any way to suppress this deprecation warning, or to indicate the compiler that I have already handled the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853184/suppressing-line-specific-xcode-compiler-warnings) question that assumes that **yes**, this is the correct way of dealing with deprecated methods, and **no**, there is no way to suppress deprecation warnings on a per-case basis, but there are hacks to mislead the compiler.

To deal with the example case, I decided to create an util class using one of these hacks:

```
@protocol UIApplicationDeprecated

- (void) setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end

@implementation UIUtils

+ (void) setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:)]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:hidden withAnimation:animated ? UIStatusBarAnimationSlide : UIStatusBarAnimationNone]; 
    } else { 
        id<UIApplicationDeprecated> app = (id)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setStatusBarHidden:hidden animated:animated];
    }
}

@end
```

If I'm not mistaken using `respondsToSelector` is costly. This could be optimized for performance to remember if the new selector is present after the first query, thus avoiding the need for reflection in subsequent calls.

Coming from a Java background, I find this way of dealing with deprecation appalling and I still can't believe that this is how iOS designers expect us to deal with this problem. More thoughts on the subject will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a better answer, but what I did once was:

1 check if the `deprecatedMethod` is available. (using `respondsToSelector:` method)

2 if yes then call that method using objective-c runtime function:

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

when using this function the compiler won't give you any warnings :)

3 other wise use the new method

Answer (score 0):

Invoking method this way:

`id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)`

will be better choise in case you want to omit warning that UIApplication may not respond to `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` method (in iOS 3.0 or later).